# Hide autogenerated content of XML annotations in Springfox Api-docs

Tags: java, xml, spring, xsd, swagger

I am writing a Gradle project with Springfox-swagger-ui 3.0.0 to present nice swagger UI with Api documentation.

```
compileOnly "io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:3.0.0"
```

One of api endpoints returns a POJO class, that is an auto-generated class from .xsd schema using XJC task.

What I'd like to do is to prevent Swagger from including auto-generated Xml-annotations

Example POJO class (generated from xsd schema):

```
@Getter
public class TestPojo {
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String machineSerialNumber;
}
```

Generated api-docs:

```
"TestPojo": {
  "type": "object",
  "title": "TestPojo",
  "properties": {
     "machineSerialNumber": {
       "type": "string",
       "xml": {
          "name": "machineSerialNumber",
          "attribute": false,
          "wrapped": false
       }
     }
  }
}
```

[image: Screen from swagger UI]

What I'd like to achieve, is to not present these xml-annotations, so that api-docs content will look like this:

```
"TestPojo": {
 "type": "object",
 "properties": {
   "machineSerialNumber": {
     "type": "string"
   }
 },
"title": "TestPojo"
}
```

And swagger-ui model:

[image: desired swagger-ui]

The problem here is that I cannot change the content of auto-generated classes to remove these annotations.
Is there a way to configure Swagger in a way so that it skips these annotations?

Comment: [You are not alone](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/3153)